# Evaluate expression as a column name

Tags: sql, postgresql, eval

I would like to use the result of an expression as a column name.

For example I have a table "cbr" with the only row

```
--QUERY_1
SELECT * FROM cbr;

 value_usd | value_uah | value_kzt | value_rur 
-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------
   57.0861 |   2.15257 |  0.171365 |         1


--QUERY_2
SELECT value_usd from cbr;

 value_usd 
-----------
   57.0861


--QUERY_3
SELECT 'value_'||'usd' from cbr;

 ?column?  
-----------
 value_usd
(1 row)
```

I would like QUERY_3 to return the same result as QUERY_2.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best choice is to normalize the table structure by adding a column for currency and a row for each value as @Clodoaldo Neto stated.  If this can't be done, dynamic SQL is you next best option.  Note that it must be used inside a pl/pgsql code.  Here's an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetCurrencyValue(Currency text)
RETURNS SETOF DOUBLE PRECISION AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT value_'||Currency||' from cbr;';
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This function takes in the parameter "Currency" and uses it as part of the column name.  You can then get the result of your second query by calling this function:

```
--Updated QUERY_3
SELECT * FROM GetCurrencyValue('usd');
```

Comment: I have psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.5
It looks like your solution does not work here.
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type double precision does not match expected type numeric in column 1.

Comment: What's the data type of your value columns?  I had assumed they were decimals, are they doubles?  If so, then you'll need to change the return type of the function from SETOF DECIMAL to SETOF DOUBLE PRECISION.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize the table:

```
create table cbr (
    currency char(3),
    value numeric
);

insert into cbr (currency, value) values 
    ('usd',57.0861),('uah',2.15257),('kzt',0.171365),('rur',1)
;

select *
from cbr
where currency = 'usd'
;
 currency |  value  
----------+---------                                                                                                                                                      
 usd      | 57.0861
```